# Не запускается WebSocket Server на VPS

Tags: node.js, веб-программирование, websocket, сокеты, vps

Возникла необходимость использовать WebSocket на Node.js. Локальный сервер работал на ура и поэтому я решил, что необходимо переносить сервер на VDS (ОС: CentOS 6). Установил все необходимое, все библиотеки и т.д. Начинаю запуск, ошибок нет, но и никакого соединение извне получить невозможно. В чем может быть проблема? Пробовал проверять и браузером и чем угодно, не работает ни на 80 порту ни на 8888 ни так далее. Сам IP пингуется.

Вот основа:

```
var WebSocketServer = new require('ws');
var read = new require('read'); //пропускаем, это для отлова ввода

//тоже пропускаем, данные клиентов
var clients = {}; 
    clientsData = {};
    messageData = {};
    gameData = {};

//параметры address и port задаются через argv - исправно работает
var webSocketServer = new WebSocketServer.Server({
    host: address, //использую основной ip-адрес VDS-сервера
    port: port //использую 80, 8888, 8080, 8081
});

console.log("Server is started");
for(var key in webSocketServer.options){
    console.log(key + " : " + webSocketServer.options[key]);
}
```

Comment: в iptables вроде все норм, хотя черт его знает, пытался открыть 80 на всякий, SELinux отключен, IP белый

Comment: Все, я справился, спасибо за наводку, файрвол настроил, работает